# Angular: perform http request in for cycle

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to perform HTTP request for each entity in array. I see two ways:

For cycle:

```
for (const i of entitiesToDelete) {
      this.apiService.deleteOne(i).subscribe(data => {
           console.log('deleted', i);
        });
}
```

forkJoin:

```
var requests = entitiesToDelete.map(e => this.apiService.deleteOne(e));

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(data => {
 for (const i of data) {
      console.log('deleted', i);
 }
});
```

There is a little difference: `for` will log to console in order of http calls are finished, whereas `forkJoin` will log to console when all requests are executed.

I am just trying to ensure that this is not an antipattern nor I am breaking some best practice.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: I am not sure if they are anti-patterns, I've seen both used several times.  I would suggest however that it would be more efficient to add a deleteMany method to your api that accepts an array of ids to be deleted, then return a result object that indicated success or failure and in the case of the lattter a list of states you can use to report on each item.  This IMHO is a better approach pushing the responsibility for multiple deletes to the backend rather than the front end

Comment: yup, if you got control with the backend. It's much better to have a api endpoint that allows for deleting multiple models

Comment: Thanks! I fully agree. However, this is the case where I have no impact on API, I have to use it the way it has been provided.

Comment: The issue with the `for` loop is you end up with multiple subscriptions. Given they are HTTP requests, they theoretically should all complete after the emission. But if the HTTP request doesn't complete and you aren't explicitly closing the subscription (eg. using `timeout`), you might end up with multiple hanging subscriptions. `forkJoin` on the other hand would let you handle it more elegantly since there's effectively only one subscription. So I'd say it's better to use `forkJoin` in this case.